# What was the reason for the cancellation of 1899 after the first season?

Tags: production, 1899

*1899* was cancelled by Netflix after its first season.

According to [the Wikipedia article on *1899*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1899_(TV_series)),

> Netflix announced a few days after release that *1899* was in 58 countries the most watched product of all the offerings available on Netflix at that time. Despite this, on 2 January 2023, the show was cancelled.

I haven't been able to find the reason for the cancellation of a highly anticipated and seemingly successful series, created by the creators of another similarly successful series.

Has the reason for the cancellation ever surfaced?

Comment: Were they the 58 smallest countries on Earth?

Comment: Did the production hit choppy waters? Did the renewal process run aground? Did sunk costs drag the show below the waterline? Or did Netflix only realise once they got around to watching it that it was not, in fact, [yet another prequel to Yellowstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowstone_(American_TV_series)#Spin-offs)?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Loads of people watched the first episode, then didn't bother watching the second. That's never a good sign

Comment: More episodic shows can market new seasons more-or-less independently from old ones. But for a heavily story-based show like 1899, the potential audience for season 2 is essentially limited to the people who watched the first season to completion, which is almost by definition smaller than the audience for the show when it was first released. (Of course that's short-run thinking; there are still shows from the 90s that I rewatch and recommend to friends because they tell a complete story. The ones that were cancelled simply lose all future interest)

Comment: It feels like the number of people that watch the show in the first few days after release is more a result of marketing success than the actual quality of the show. As someone who did watch the entire first season hoping the ending would make it worthwhile... well, I would not watch the second season if they made one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to this interview with the creators, it was too expensive and the audience reach didn't justify the expense.

> ..but it wasn't enough to guarantee a second season. **Netflix chose to
> cancel production on the grounds that it was too expensive and had not
> reached a relevant audience enough to maintain itself.** The creators do
> not hide their disappointment and are still trying to understand the
> impact of the decision.
>
> *"The cancellation of “1899” changed the way we think about our projects
> a lot. Things have changed a lot in the industry and in society,
> especially in the way people produce and consume content. We really
> believe that if “Dark” were released now, it wouldn’t have any chance
> — laments Odar. — We have so much content in the world today that
> people are always consuming things quickly and without dedication.
> With the cancellation, we had to think about whether our storytelling
> is something people still want and whether we should adjust it.
> Honestly, we don't have an answer yet."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Creators of 'Dark' and '1899' talk about new series and accusation of plagiarism: 'it was one of the most painful moments' (Google Translated from Portuguese)](https://oglobo.globo.com/cultura/streaming/noticia/2023/04/criadores-de-dark-e-1899-falam-sobre-nova-serie-e-acusacao-de-plagio-foi-um-dos-momentos-mais-dolorosos.ghtml)</sup></sub>

As regards the audience figures, although it had good opening figures, the "completion rate" was appalling, with less than a third of Episode 1 viewers sticking with it until the final episode.

> Netflix doesn’t share this info with the public, but according to data
> analytics company Digital i (via What’s On Netflix), 1899’s completion
> rate was just 32 percent.
>
> <sub><sup>[The secret Netflix metric that got 1899 canceled — and could ruin TV forever](https://www.inverse.com/culture/1899-canceled-netflix-completion-rates)</sup></sub>